# Using libc++ instead of libstdc++ in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, clang, c++14, libc++

I have **clang++ 3.5**, **g++ 4.9.1**, **libc++** and **Qt Creator** installed on **Ubuntu 14.04.1**.

I usually use **clang++** as compiler. But recently I found that **libstdc++** from **g++** used as *C++ Standard Library*. As I know the latter not fully supports *C++14* innovations at the moment.

How to replace **libstd++** with **libc++** when project compiled with **clang++**?

What I already done (`.pro`-file):

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_CXX11 = -std=gnu++1y
CONFIG *= c++11
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++
LIBS += -stdlib=libc++
```

But the **Qt Creator** editor still uses **libstdc++** as `DEPENDPATH` when crawling through included files. How to fix such ill behaviour? Maybe should I fix something in *mkspec* files?

Comment: did you look at: http://libcxx.llvm.org/

Comment: @TemplateRex Yes, I did.

Answer (score 2):

The standard library is specified in the mkspec files.

In linux, you can use : qmake -spec linux-clang-libc++

I think the equivalent in qtcreator is to define a new "kit" and specify "linux-clang-libc++" in the field "Qt mkspec"

Comment: Please, reread the question. There is no problem how to specify for `clang` what stdlib to use. Thre is problem with autocomplete and other features of the editor itself. I want on <kbd>F2</kbd> onto `std::map` click to jump to *libc++*'s `std::map` header, not to *libstdc++*s one.

Comment: Sorry. I thought you were having problem with boths.